# Why are female counterparts in South Indian temples placed on the right?

Tags: rama, temple, sita, tamil

[image: Vaduvur Ramar Kalyana Utsavam]

Google search for Sri Rama temples in Tamilnadu returns many similar images, with Sita on the right of Rama, as well as many pictures with her being on the left, as usual elsewhere for Lakshmi-Narayana, Sita-Rama, Radha-Krishna etc. Why are South Indian temples so different in this regard?

Comment: It's related with chit shakti on right side and prana on left aide of body. Chit is Shiva and prana is shakti. Same way its opposite for shakti. For shakti Shiva is left side and shakti is right side. That's why vishnu temples have sita right and Shiva temples have shakti left. Agamas have this as base

Comment: @ParabrahmanJyoti Not sure I follow. Sita is usually on the left of Rama, as is usual for all Vishnu forms, and Parvati is usually on Siva's left, too. But sometimes it is changed. The accepted answer below and comments there explain why. Are you trying to say something different?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the temple is depicting the specific scenario of the deities during marriage then it's correct that the female deity is placed to the right of the male deity.

Because we have from the Atri Smriti:

> A woman is [always] the left limb, the husband being alive or dead ;
> and he the right one. But in a Sraddha, sacrifice, **and marriage, a
> wife should always [be placed] in the right**. (138)

Comment: I think in most of worship rituals, wife sits on right..but on other occasions, on left..

Comment: @YDS in rituals where brahmacharya is to be maintained it’s on the right and in which the wife is an important part then it’s left

Comment: yes @YDS, mentioned in the verse given that in Yajna/worship wife should sit at the right of the husband.