# Wife's seating position during rituals

Tags: rituals, puja, homam, wife

I heard from someone that during religious rituals (puja, homa, etc.) wife should sit on left side of husband.

But my understanding was wife sits on the right side of husband.

Any views in our scriptures on the positioning? In which rituals (deities like puja/homa, samskaras like marriage/upanayana and pitru shraddhas) wife is sitting in left and which ones on right?

Comment: "But my understanding was wife is always right and should already sit on right side." -- why do u think so? wife is referred as Vaamangi and remains left side always.. but in puja, she sits on right side... i think u asked Q in opposite way.. or it's different custom in ur area?

Comment: See the following answer: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/46165/4732

Comment: @yds I have reworded the question.  Reading the link rickross shared, it's not clear which situations wife is sitting left and when on right side. Please can you explain/answer. At our home wife sits on right side for pujas/homas.

Comment: @rickross see above comment please. I couldn't tag both of you in same comment.

Comment: @Kanthri During performance of rituals, Shraddhas and during marriage the wife should sit on the right of the husband but in all other occasions she is considered as the left limb. My answer there answers your query.

Comment: @rickross "all other occasions" like in social settings? If so, then I have the answer. Thank you.

Comment: Yes that's right. Only occasions when wife should sit on the right are Yajnas, shraddas and during her marriage. @Kanthri